# Bind Datagridview to StringCollection

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, .net-2.0

Is it possible to bind Datagridview to StringCollection ?
I tried to do it in a manner

```
    StringCollection dict = Settings.Default.MyDict;
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = dict;
    this.DGV.DataSource = bs;
```

Bud instead of items of the collection datagridview shows lengths of the items.

Comment: Possible duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104341/net-c-sharp-binding-iliststring-to-a-datagridview

Comment: its not a duplicate, its for .net2.0

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when it binds to `StringCollection`, the underlying type is `string` so it pulls out the first property that it finds from type `string` to display. That property is Length.

What you can do is wrap your `StringCollection` in a class of your own making and expose a property that will display the `string`'s text.

Wrapper class for `string`:

```
public class MyString
{
    private string _myString;

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _myString; }
        set { _myString = value; }
    }

    public MyString(string str)
    {
        _myString = str;
    }
}
```

Your code becomes:

```
StringCollection dict = Settings.Default.MyDict; 
// put your string in the wrapper
List<MyString> anotherdict = new List<MyString>();
foreach (string str in dict)
{
    anotherdict.Add(new MyString(str));
}
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
// bind to the new wrapper class
bs.DataSource = anotherdict;
this.DGV.DataSource = bs;
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it without wrapper by changing DataMember property?

Comment: @Ask, `DataMember` takes the name of a Property. If you look at [String's Public Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_members(v=vs.80).aspx) you'll see it only has two properties, and neither one gets you the text of the string. So, there is nothing you can set `DataMember` to that will get you the text. The only way around it is to provide your own class that supplies its own Property exposing the string. Instead of `StringCollection` could you use `List<>`, or `BindingList<>`, or `ObservableCollection`, etc.?

Comment: Thanks for comment. By default you can choose only StringCollection in  property editor, thats why I'm stuck on it.