# String array from txt file into datagridview

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, datagridview

I have a text file that contains a file path on each line.
Using this code below, i turn all the paths into an array of strings, and try to display them in the datagridview.

```
string[] filePathList = File.ReadAllLines(txtBatchFile);
dataGridView1.DataSource = filePathList;
```

But instead of displaying the strings, it is now displaying the length of the strings.
How do i make it display the strings?

Considering i want to be able to add more data into the grid and save it back to the text file, should i even be using a string array like this or are there better alternatives?

Comment: Post some minimal xaml of your GridView please.

Comment: Same question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140487/bind-datagridview-to-stringcollection

Comment: @eranotzap Its in Forms, not WPF so i dont think i have xaml there.

Comment: @silvesthu didnt see that one yet, thank you ill check it out.