# How to populate a dataGridView with an array of user generated integers

Tags: c#, arrays, datagridview

With this:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = theData.Select((x, index) =>
    new { CreatureRoll = x, CreatureLabel = index}).OrderByDescending(x =>    x.CreatureRoll).ToList();
```

It produces the data correctly, But it produces all the rows in the array with extra data that will not be useful, empty data.

[img http://s21.postimg.org/t3f34aa43/list_Result.jpg?noCache=1379353500](http://s21.postimg.org/t3f34aa43/list_Result.jpg?noCache=1379353500)

Would like to remove unnecessary rows of data

Comment: *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.*

Comment: Give some more detail like how many row it have ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ to generate the datasource from a array.

```
int[] theData = new int[] { 14, 17, 5, 11, 2 };
dataGridView1.DataSource = theData.Where(x => x>0).Select((x, index) =>
    new { RecNo = index + 1, ColumnName = x }).OrderByDescending(x => x.ColumnName).ToList();
```

[image]

Comment: Since my array length is 100 I'm ending up with a bunch of extra rows that are not necessary. Is there any way for me to be able to set the amount of rows to be generated equal to the amount of written data in the array?

Comment: you better use `List<int>`  and add values to it. can you update the question with your code?

Comment: With an array, you can also use the `Where` method (that is already in the answer), to filter what values won't enter the grid.

Answer (score 12):

You can have code like this also,

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Index", "Index");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Value", "Dice Value");
int[] theData = new int[] { 5, 2, 1, 5, 4, 1, 3, 1};

for (int i = 0; i < theData.Length; i++)
{
     dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { i+1, theData[i] });
}
```

**Output** 
[image]

Comment: So, this managed to work for me but there is one more thing i need to add to the list and that would be the label for each roll.

Comment: You mean instead index you want label text ?

Comment: Well, I have a counter and the counter "creatureLabel" is marking each roll the user generated in the original text box. i. e.             ("\n" + creatureLabel + ". " + theData[i] + " ");

Comment: Ok what i assume is you have successfully sorted data and you have array of string like "2. 17 1. 14 4. 11 3. 5 5. 2" No you want to display it on grid view with, right ?

Comment: yes, that's pretty much what im going for. Damith's code is on the right track too

Comment: Okay thanks for the code snipits, I managed to figure out what to do based on your stuff and everyone elses. Thanks very much :D

Comment: Ohh it's ok i also get something that i have to learn LINQ :p thanks to damith, well i will see what can i do, I had download some sample code and start learning now.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this [.NET / C# Binding IList<string> to a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104341/net-c-sharp-binding-iliststring-to-a-datagridview)

Setting the datasource to an array will not display anything. Basically the values need to have a named property and need to implement IList to be able to be used as a DataSource. Something like this should do your bidding.

```
var array = new int[] { 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dataGridView1.DataSource = array.Select(x => new { IntValue = x }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int[] ints = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
gvMain.DataSource = ints;
gvMain.DataBind();
```

`gvMain` is a GridView, You can Add user generated array instead of `ints`.

Answer (score 0):

how to assign the collection for below situation:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dropDT.Rows)
{
     values.Add(dr[0].ToString());
}

dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value = values;
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value = values;
```