# adding datarow[] array to a datagridview using c# forms

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, dataset, datarow

I currently have the ff codes. My problem is how do I get the datarow[] array data and show it to a datagridview table.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();    
Data dt = ds.Tables["Tables"];
string path = Application.StartupPath + "\\test.xml";
Int MdNum = 1;

//assign xmlfile to data set
ds.ReadXml(path);

//create datarow array and get tables that has md_id=1
DataRow[] result = dt.Select("[MD_ID] = " + MdNum);

//create datagrid columns
dataGridView2.Columns.Add("Column", "TBL_ID");
dataGridView2.Columns.Add("Column", "TBL_Name");
dataGridView2.Columns.Add("Column", "MD_ID");
dataGridView2.Columns.Add("Column", "IsRequired");
```

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820151/how-to-populate-a-datagridview-with-an-array-of-user-generated-integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create view and set it as datasource

```
DataView view = new DataView(dt);

view.RowFilter = "MD_ID = " +MdNum;

dataGridView2.DataSource = view;
```

Or you can use `CopyToDataTable` method

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = result.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: The DataView Worked for me and got the expected data needed. Thank you so much Damith!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Datagridview without a `Datasource`:

If the Datarow has the same columns in the same order as your Datagridview you can simply write:

```
for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    dataGridView2.Rows.Add(result[i].ItemArray);
}
```