# Cannot implicility convert type string[] to system.windows.forms.DatagGridViewColumn in C3#

Tags: c#

Here is my code,

```
string[] str = {"colSelect",
            "colBRVStatus",
            "colRowNumber",
            "colSectionId",
            "colPlanogramdbkey",
            "colPog_name",
            "colPog_Category",
            "colSize",
            "colPog_Equipment",
            "colPog_Cluster",
            "colPog_Variation",
            "colPog_EventType",
            "colPog_Status",
            "colPog_Pendingdate",
            "colPog_Livedate",
            "colPog_State",
            "colRangeState",
            "colBasestoreVal",
            "colStore_Attached",
            "colPog_Version_Identifier",
            "colRangeCode",
            "colNonVisualPOG",
            "colOneBayApproxCompletionTime",
            "colRangeCheckStatus",
            "colAutoPOGAcpt",
            "colSuppressMPLCalc",
            "colPGType",
            "colPGTemplateKey",
            "colPOGLockStatus"};

            List<DataGridViewColumn[]> ldgvcols = new List<DataGridViewColumn[]>();
ldgvcols.Add(new DataGridViewColumn[] { str});
```

Comment: I think you can find the solution on the following link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820151/how-to-populate-a-datagridview-with-an-array-of-user-generated-integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820151/how-to-populate-a-datagridview-with-an-array-of-user-generated-integers)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

`new DataGridViewColumn[] { a, b, c, ...}`

The values a, b, c, etc. are assumed to be of type `DataGridViewColumn` and C# tries to create a new DataGridViewColumn array containing the values a, b, c, etc. Your `str` is of type `string[]` and cannot be converted to `DataGridViewColumn`.

If you want to convert your `string[]` into a `DataGridViewColumn[]`, you would need to loop over each element in `str` and create a `DataGridViewColumn` for each string using whatever logic you see fit. Alternatively, you can use Linq's Select method instead of looping:

```
List<DataGridViewColumn> list = new List<DataGridViewColumn>();

for(var s in str){
   DataGridViewColumn dataCol = ... //create a DataGridViewColumn using s however you like
   list.Add(dataCol);
}

DataGridViewColumn[] dataGridViewColumnArray = list.ToArray();
```

Comment: Then what i can do for the conversion or  assigning  value to column.But it's possible to do or not.

Comment: Check the edits I made. Don't forget to upvote if the answer helped you!

Comment: When i am assign s to  datacol it shows same conversion error.

Comment: Check this on how to programatically set the vaue:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516252/how-to-programmatically-set-cell-value-in-datagridview